# Getting error from pygame font function

Tags: python, pygame

I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\testclientUDP.py", line 61, in <module>
    screen(TEXT, WHITE)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\testclientUDP.py", line 38, in screen
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'font'
```

My code is:

```
def screen(TEXT, COLOUR):
    screen1.fill(COLOUR)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 25, True, False)
    text = font.render(TEXT, True, BLACK)
    screen1.blit(text, [150, 230])
    pygame.display.flip()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please show where you initialize `pygame`

Comment: `import pygame
from pygame.locals import * pygame.init()` Right at the beginning and I initialize the screen before the function and call the function in a while loop `while True:
    screen(TEXT, WHITE)
    pygame = pygame.event.get()`

Comment: I would guess that you forgot to call `pygame.init()` before your loop. See answer below

Comment: You overwrite the original value of `pygame` here: `pygame = pygame.event.get()`

Comment: @Matthias changed my `pygame = pygame.event.get()` to `control = pygame.event.get()` it works awesome now. I never thought that a variable would mess with a function, but as im writing this I see now why it is doing what it is doing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `pygame.font.init()` or `pygame.init()` before any other function

According to the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html)

> **pygame.font.init()**
>
> *initialize the font module*
>
> This method is called automatically by pygame.init(). It initializes the font module. The module must be initialized before any other functions will work

Comment: According to the comments `pygame.init()` was called.

Comment: OK, but `'list' object has no attribute 'font'` clearly shows that `pygame` is not what it should be. With your solution you would call `init()` on a list object.